# Is there a way to edit file properties on Android to include some sort of "watermark" for my translated subtitle files?

Tags: android, windows, metadata, watermark, file-properties

## How to edit file properties on Android like on Windows? Or are there any other way to do similar operation?

Doesn't have to be the exact and complete metadata line to edit, I just want to put some sort of "watermark" to my translated subtitle files (on its file properties, extension: SRT) so that it could be traced back to me – the translator. Is there any way to do that?

Unfortunately, I don't have access to a PC at the moment.

*Sorry for my bad English*

Comment: Windows file properties only exist in your file-system so they are lost if you transfer the file to a different system. The same is for all meta data you can store in file-system in Android/Linux.